# Transferring of the Master Page finished with the failure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, master-page, integration

There are two SharePoint sites, each based on its own SharePoint installation. I have to copy the Master Page from one site to another.

I moved an items from Master Page Gallery, then I registered dlls are referred by ones. But dlls link to another elements what I can’t find on server. Eventually I have a broken page with message: “The type of control Eos.SharePoint.Common.Controls.BreadCrumbsControl is forbidden. This type isn’t found or not registered as safe” (Eos.SharePoint.Common – one of loaded and registered dlls). I’m not find the file “Eos.SharePoint.Common.Controls.BreadCrumbsControl” in the server file system (Where does it locate?).

SharePoint site, from where I try to transfer the Master Page, had been developed by other people. And I haven’t the list of a deployed assets to compose a Web Solution Package. I have not even found Visual Studio or SharePoint Designer on the server. So maybe I haven’t a necessary resources. Should I stop?

Do you have an experience with similar problems? Maybe an another ways exists e.g. displaying a set of Web Parts in the proper Master Page via frames (Page Viewer Web Part, Embed Code)?

Help me, Guys!!!)))

Answer (score 0):

You can download an existing WSP file on your Farm using Powershell:

```
$frm = Get-SPFarm
$file = $frm.Solutions.Item("Eos.SharePoint.Common.wsp").SolutionFile
$file.SaveAs("c:\wsp\Eos.SharePoint.Common.wsp")
```

If you want to use it in any other web application, just go to Central Administration -> Solution Management -> click System Settings -> Manage Farm Solutions

Look for `Eos.SharePoint.Common.wsp` and activate it on your second web application as well.